# RestSharp on Windows Phone with Request Parameters

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth, restsharp

I'm working on Windows phone client for one service with Oauth1 API.

In API docs I have something like this:

`url: http://example.com/iphone/json/users/`

`method: GET`

parameters: 
page_num=[int] - page number, >=1, default=1.

For default page num everything works well:

```
        RestClient HabraClient = new RestClient("http://habrahabr.ru");
        HabraClient.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource("xxx", "yyyyyy", App.Tokens.Key, App.Tokens.Secret);
        var TokenRequest = new RestRequest("/iphone/json/users/", Method.GET);

        HabraClient.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest, (response =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
```

When I execute this request I receive correct response with data.
But if I add parameter (uncomment TokenRequest.AddParameter("page_num", 2); ) I receive "Invalid signature". I have tried to send both int and string parameter.

```
        var TokenRequest = new RestRequest("/iphone/json/users/", Method.GET);

        TokenRequest.AddParameter("page_num", 2);

        HabraClient.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest, (response =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
```

I receive message "Invalid signature". I have tried string parameter too:

```
        TokenRequest.AddParameter("page_num", "2");
```

API provider told me, that I have a problem with signature base 
string http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#sig_base_example 
So, how can i view it? Or maybe you can help me to solve all this 
problem?

Comment: can you post more complete examples of the working version _and_ the non-working version?

Comment: How are you generating the signature?

Comment: John, I have updated post.
Matt, signature is generated by API and I'm trying to find a way, how to see it in debugger :)

Comment: You could see the signature being generated with something like Fiddler. It's possible their signature algorithm doesn't match the one in RestSharp (I have seen some APIs have subtle differences). Also if you just hardcode the querystring value into the RestRequest constructor URL parameter, does that fix it?

Comment: OAuth 1 needs url parameters and form-urlencoded parameters to generate the signature

Comment: As I know, Restsharp automaticly encodes parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are breaking the request structure... better to check the request over Fiddler, but try to write something like

```
var TokenRequest = new RestRequest("/iphone/json/users/?page_num=2", Method.GET);
```

instead of

```
var TokenRequest = new RestRequest("/iphone/json/users/", Method.GET);

TokenRequest.AddParameter("page_num", 2);
```

Hope, it would help.